# Call the stored procedure in mysql in odbc. The out parameter of the stored procedure in the execution result is invalid

Tags: c++, mysql, odbc

Below is my code, the value of retCSNum used as output parameter is not changed.The SQLExecDirect function is successfully executed.

```
cout << "-------" << "Execute Procedures:" << "-------" << endl;
SQLCloseCursor(hStmt);
if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS)
    cout << "API Successfully!" << endl;
SQLCHAR countDep[SDepart_Len]= "CS";
SQLLEN countDepInd =SQL_NTS;

SQLLEN retCSNum = 0,retCSNumInd = SQL_IS_INTEGER;

ret = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR,20,NULL,countDep,SDepart_Len*sizeof(char),&countDepInd);
if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS)
    cout << "Bind Successfully!" << endl;
ret = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &retCSNum, sizeof(int), &retCSNumInd);
if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS)
    cout << "Bind Successfully!" << endl;

ret = SQLExecDirect(hStmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call CSNum(?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
SQLCHAR* state2 = new SQLCHAR[5];
cout << retCSNum << endl; // print 0
```

Comment: see tha mysql example on thehomepage for prepared statements https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-tutorials-stored-routines-prepared-statement-out-parameter.html

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

1. Modify "{call CSNum(?,?)}" to "call CSNum(?,?)"
2. do not use procedures_name.parameter_name in your procedures,it is not allowed in mysql.